# Can I declare a local variable not null?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL, I declare a local variable for use with some query like so:

```
DECLARE @var_last datetime;
SET @var_last = (SELECT TOP(1) col_date FROM tbl_dates ORDER BY col_date);
```

In an application I'm testing, it would be an error for this query to return NULL, and it's desirable for the query to return a crash error if it were.

I'd like to set `@var_last` to be `NOT NULL` but the syntax...

```
DECLARE @var_last datetime NOT NULL;
```

...is invalid. I can write a simple check on the return of the query to see if it's NULL, and error if it is, but my question is, is it not possible to declare a local variable as NOT NULL?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this and I guess I don't know why you would want to.

Comment: Unclear question: "I'd like to set @var_last to be NOT NULL but the syntax" is different to "is it possible to declare a local variable as NOT NULL?". **SET** refers to the value, where as **DECLARE** refers to the type. You definitely can't have a value of "NOT NULL" because if something is not null it must have a specific value in Sql Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's right, according the documentation for the `DECLARE @local_variable`, available at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx, it doesn't accept a `NULL | NOT NULL` parameter -- those are only valid for column definitions.

If you want to stop execution if you return a `NULL`, then test for `NULL` and, if it is, `RAISERROR`; see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this ...

**Using ISNULL()**

```
SELECT TOP(1) @var_last = ISNULL(col_date,'19000101') --<-- Some default value
FROM tbl_dates 
ORDER BY col_date;
```

**Using COALESCE()**

```
SELECT TOP(1) @var_last = COALESCE(col_date,'19000101') --<-- Some default value
FROM tbl_dates 
ORDER BY col_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set a variable to `NOT NULL` because `NULL` and `NOT NULL` are states, not values (even tho you can set a variable to `NULL` which looks like you are setting a value but you are actually erasing the existing value).

NULL, by definition, means has no value.

Comment: In sql server NULL means `unknown value`, not No Value :)

Comment: @M.Ali you are technically correct (which is the best kind of correct), however for practical purposes I don't see the difference. If a variable or column in a row had a value then I can't see how it could be unknown.

Comment: In your answer you have mentioned BY Definition, I'll have to disagree with this. NULL is strictly considered an UNKNOWN value in sql server yes in other programming language it is considered No value but in sql server NULLs are treated differently. Please read here for [`Documentation On NULL Values`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @M.Ali Even after reading the link, I'm still comfortable with my interpretation. I totally agree that "A value of NULL is different from an empty or zero value", but my perspective is that NULL signifies that no value has been recorded in the database. Whether or not the value is unknown is not something that can be determined by SQL Server. In the example given, who is to say that the user didn't actually know the customer's middle initial but just chose not to enter it. Is the value then truly unknown?

Comment: The original question is unclear (see comment on question) but I'd assume he wants the _type_ to be not _nullable_, so that the value can range over DateTime but never be null. This is possible for a column definition but I don't think it is for a variable.