# DECLARE @bitVariable BIT NOT NULL -- how (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server

This should be easy, but it doesn't make sense...

The following code works without issue:

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
  , TestBit BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , SomeDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @testTable (SomeDate) VALUES(GETDATE())

SELECT * FROM @testTable
```

However, I am trying to do something simple:

```
DECLARE @test BIT NOT NULL = 0 
select @test
```

But I get an error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'NOT'.
```

Is it not possible to declare a bit variable NOT NULL or do I just leave off the NOT NULL and assign the default value? It seems odd that you can do it in one place (table variable) but not the other (variable).

Comment: You just leave the NOT NULL off when declaring a scalar variable.  The one in your example that works is declaring a table variable which can have NULL as column values.

Comment: In the first part your creating a table with a nullable bit field.  In the second one you're just declaring a bit variable.  You are not able to specify that a variable cannot be null, so the NOT NULL part is invalid syntax, so that should be ommitted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I declare a local variable not null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900979/can-i-declare-a-local-variable-not-null) T-SQL is full of oddities, don't let it get to you.